# Using GoogleCL to upload Youtube Videos

Tags: api, upload, youtube, cmd, googlecl

What is the correct command line to upload multiple videos with description and tags to youtube using googlecl?

```
youtube post sample1.wmv sample2.wmv
```

The above code uploads both videos fine, but I would like to add summary and tags and can't figure out where to put --summary and --tags appropriately. Or is a batch command file a better option for multiple videos? If so, what is the structure of such batch file, because googlecl does not respond to normal .bat files.

Thanks

Comment: thanks, but when i type command like that i end up with the first file uploaded and summary as "blabla"\nyoutube post foo2.wmv --tags "moomoo"

Comment: I meant type the two commands on two lines, I haven't used bash in a long time but I think they should be run seperately then.

Answer (score 1):

A more complete example, which avoids the "public" access default:

```
youtube post foo1.wmv --title "my cool video" --summary "your summary here" --tags "tag1, note tags separated by commas, third tag" --access unlisted --category Travel
```

See more at https://code.google.com/p/googlecl/wiki/ExampleScripts#Youtube